# S3 objects have been deleted randomly

Tags: amazon-s3, sorl-thumbnail

Is there a command in AWS CLI to restore Versioning files?

i've been developing a web server using Django
someday i found there was deleted image files randomly in S3
i think Django sorl-thumbnail will delete it
and tried to fix it but it failed
So I thought of temporary solution.
AWS S3 is delivering versioning. i use it to recover manually every day.
This is very Annoying to do, so I am writing a script.
But I could not find a way to restore a file with a delete marker.
Does anyone know the situation above?
 thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Recovering of objects is a bit tricky in s3. As per AWS documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingObjects.html

When you delete an object from a versioned bucket, S3 creates a new object called a **delete marker**, which has its own, new version ID.

If you delete that "version" of the object, it will restore your object's visibility.

You can use this command

```
aws s3api delete-object --bucket <bucket> --key <key> --version-id <version_id_of_delete_marker>
```

Comment: Thanks, @jzaa. Downvote replaced with upvote.  Also, I fleshed out and clarified your answer a bit.